# Converting values of old columns into new columns, and using old values of paired columns as values in the new columns

Tags: python, pandas, format, schema, data-cleaning

I've been tasked with cleaning data from a mobile application designed by a charity

In one section, a users Q/A app use session is represented by a row. This section consists of repeated question answer field pairs, where a field represents the question asked and then the field next to it represents the corresponding answer. Together, each question/field and answer column pair represent a unique question with the answer.

Starting data

```
_id                     answers.1.answer answers.0.fieldName answers.1.answer    answers.1.fieldName

5f27f29c362a380d3f9a9e46    1.0           enjoyment              20.0        affectedkneeside           
5f27f2ac362a380d3f9a9e4b    0.0           fatigue2weeks          40.0        avoidexercise             
5f27f4d4362a380d3f9a9e52    1.0           height                 50.0        painlocationknee
```

[image]

I have been asked to reformat the section so each question forms a column, the corresponding answer a field in that column

The ideal output

```
_id                    avoidexercise    enjoyment   fatigue2weeks   height
        
5f27f29c362a380d3f9a9e46    1.0           yes            20.0       120.0
5f27f2ac362a380d3f9a9e4b    0.0           no             40.0       180.0
5f27f4d4362a380d3f9a9e52    1.0           yes            50.0       150.0
```

My plan is to create many pivot tables, from each other Q/A pairs of columns, then concaternate (outer join) then inner join to remove duplications

However, the original dataframe contains a mixture of numeric and object datatypes

Therefore, only some question/answer column pairs appear to be converting to pivot tables. I have tried using various aggregate functions

```
p1 = ur.pivot_table(index=['_id'],columns= ['answers.0.fieldName'],values=['answers.0.answer'],aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(x))
p2 = ur.pivot_table(index=['_id'],columns= ['answers.1.fieldName'],values=['answers.1.answer'],aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(x))
p3 = ur.pivot_table(index=['_id'],columns= ['answers.2.fieldName'],values=['answers.2.answer'],aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(x))
```

I have also tried another lambda function

```
p1 = ur.pivot_table(index=['_id'],columns= ['answers.0.fieldName'],values=['answers.0.answer'],aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(str(v) for v in x)
```

The furthest I have got so far is to run pivots with standard mean aggfunc

```
p1 = ur.pivot_table(index=['_id'],columns=['answers.0.fieldName'],values=['answers.0.answer'])
ps = [p1,p2,p3]
c = pd.concat(ps)
```

Then attempting to remove merge rows and columns

```
df = c.sum(axis=1, level=1, skipna=False)

g = df.groupby('_id').agg(np.sum)
```

This returns a dataframe with the right shape

However, it looses the values in the object columns, and I'm not sure how accurate all the numeric columns are

To overcome this problem, I was considering converting as much data as I can into numeric

```
c4 = c.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore').info()
```

Then splitting the combined pivot table dataframe into numeric and object type

```
nu = ['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']
cndf = c4.select_dtypes(include=nu)
o = ['object', 'bool', 'datetime64', 'category']
codf = c4.select_dtypes(include=o)
```

And running through the same .sum and groupby operations as above on the numeric dataframe

```
n1 = cndf.sum(axis=1, level=1, skipna=False)
n2 = n1.groupby('_id').agg(np.sum)
```

However, this still leaves the challenge of dealing with the object columns

Comment: where does the `id` field come from ? can you update your starting df

Comment: Dear Manakin, 
a good question. The columns I am trying to convert are found in just an extract of the dataframe. 
The _ID column is found at an earlier index

Comment: your sample still doesnt make sense, you start with answer 1 but then follow it with an unrelated question. Post a proper example of your dataframe, just 2-3 answers will do.

Comment: Strangely, that is an extract from the dataframe. The answers to some of the questions are binary. Questions are encoded as field names, paired to answers in the previous column

Answer (score 0):

This is another, more elegant solution. But again does not deal with object columns

First define the number of question-answer pairs:

```
num_answers = 2 #Following your 'Starting data' in the question
```

Then use the following couple of lines to obtain a dataframe as required:

```
import pandas as pd

df2 = pd.concat([pd.pivot_table(df1, index=['_id'], columns= ['answers.{}.fieldName'.format(i)], values=['answers.{}.answer'.format(i)]) for i in range(num_answers)], axis = 1).fillna('N/A')
df2.columns = [col[1] for col in df2.columns]
```

Here df1 is assumed to be the dataframe with the starting data.

As you might have noticed, 'N/A' is present in cells where the particular id has no recorded answer for that particular field.

Assuming an ID of [1,2,3] for the three rows respectively, the output df2 for your 'Starting data' would look like this:

```
      affectedkneeside  avoidexercise   height  painlocationknee    vomitflag   weight
_id                     
0          N/A                0           N/A         N/A              0         N/A
1          N/A               N/A          156         N/A              N/A       54
2           1                N/A          N/A          3               N/A       N/A
```